# Get HTML Style to work with multiple lines of read-only data

Tags: html, styles, word-wrap

I'm using the following HTML to customize data fields displayed on a screen:

```
<a style="text-decoration-line:none;text-align:left;background:bisque;padding-right:45px;">
```

This works as expected for data fields that are displayed on a single line.  However, when I encounter a field that would result in multiple lines of data, the Style doesn't work.  a rectangle of the bisque background appears before or after the large data fields, but their background is white. 
How do I alter this Style statement to accommodate large fields which will wrap the data?  This is a read-only screen, so the  tag doesn't work for me.
Thanks for looking at this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using HTML5 this should work :

```
    <a style="text-decoration:none;">
    <div style="text-align:left;background:bisque;padding-right:45px;">
    Your multiline data here...
    </div>
    </a>
```

Comment: That did it!  Thanks.  Just FYI, the "text-decoration:none" has to go in the <a> tag. However, it was the DIV that fixed the problem!